# Can you use an input to open a Tkinter Window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently in year 11 doing computer science, im making a glossary of key terms using tkinter. I was wondering if i can use a user input to open a tkinter window.
e.g

```
topic = input("Choose a topic, 1. Theory or 2. Algorithms: ")

if topic == '1':
       then here i would call the theory tkinter window using a subroutine
```

i have tried this but it doesnt seem to work for me.

Below is the link to the whole code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDfZP.png

This is what the UI looks like so far

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zI37.png

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Take the time to create a [mcve] directly in the question.

Comment: This explains **why**: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can simply call `window.mainloop()` in the `if` statement.

Comment: is it necessary to open a new window? can't you simply "change" frames?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making it too complex, just write the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

topic = input("Choose a topic, 1. Theory or 2. Algorithms: ")
    
def topic_1():
    root = Tk()

    # Your Code here

    root.mainloop()

def topic_2():
    root = Tk()

    # Your Code here

    root.mainloop()

if topic == '2':
    topic_2()    

elif topic == '1':
    topic_1()
```

So in this code you are first supposed to take the input from your user. Based on the input, an if/else statement will call one of 2 functions which have their individual tkinter windows.

Comment: you have a typo in function name

Comment: also this could get very repetitive very soon so I would suggest using classes because I would think that the windows all will have a similar if not same structure so repeating the same code wouldn't be efficient, also you could use a dictionary instead of `if/elif` to map user input to functions

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Here this is the best I could do for you as I didn't want to re-type all of your code. I would recommend replacing windows.mainloop with a while loop and window.update

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Something")
window.geometry("1000x1000")

text_box = Text()
text_box.pack()
new_window = False


def new_window_fun():
    window2 = Tk()
    window2.title("Something new :)")
    window2.geometry("1000x1000")
    label = Label(text="Hello")
    label.pack()
    while True:
        window2.update()


try:
    while 'normal' == window.state():
        if text_box.get("1.0", END).strip() == "new window" and new_window is False:
            new_window = True
            window.destroy()  # close the current window
            new_window_fun()
            print("finished")
        else:
            window.update()
except:
    print("the end")
```

Comment: I would recommend not using `*` when importing, also instead of `while True: window.update()` use `window.mainloop()`, and also there should only be one instance of `Tk`

Comment: Yeah, I agree but I was doing my best to go along with the requirements of the question.

Comment: Colin, the question does require doing a wildcard import. I strongly advise against using a wildcard (`*`) when importing something, you should either import what you need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module`. You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or something like that, the point is that don't import everything unless you actually know what you're doing: avoiding name clashes is the goal. It it would useful to include info on *what* you're doing differently that what's in the OP's code.